# Chatterbot: installation

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, chatterbot

I have tried to install the module "Chatterbot 0.4.6",  but it fails with the following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk'
```

What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: Could your please clarify which command you use to install the package? There seems to be a permissions problem. Do you have admin rights for your computer?

Comment: I solved it with the sudo command:sudo pip install chatterbot. Now there is another problem. At the end of installation, in the shell, Python doesn't recognize the module. But the installation is successfully installed: Collecting chatterbot...Successfully installed chatterbot-0.4.6 future-0.15.2 fuzzywuzzy-0.11.1 jsondatabase-0.1.1 nltk-3.2.1 oauthlib-1.1.2 pymongo-3.3.0 python-twitter-3.1 requests-oauthlib-0.6.2 textblob-0.11.1

Comment: What do you mean by Python does not regognize the module?

Comment: Thanks. I solved also this problem. Python didn't recognize the module but I changed the position of the module in the directory.

Comment: Now chatterbot version 0.6.1, could you please try pip install --upgrade chatterbot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As correctly recommended by @Adryr83, the `sudo` command is often needed for linux platforms when installing Python packages with `pip`.

For example:

`sudo pip install chatterbot`

Comment: If you don't have sudo privileges try to use python virtual environments more information available here http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 0):

try this sudo pip3 install chatterbot

Answer (score 0):

@Adryr83 You can try installing **Chatterbot 0.4.6** using `pip install ChatterBot==0.4.6`

SOURCE: https://pypi.org/project/ChatterBot/0.4.6/